# Guaranteed precision with numerics?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, precision

I understand that due to the way floats are stored, there are some values that cannot be represented exactly. (See [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate))

That being said, in .NET / C#, what options or guarantees does one have in terms of precision? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 refers to "approximate" range. Why is an approximation necessary in this context?

Ultimately, I'm looking to store a value like:

```
x.xxxxxxxx
```

where the value is always positive. This doesn't seem to be a hugely precise number, yet I'd like to know for sure that all possible numeric combinations above are "durable."

**Edit:**

To clarify about the exact level of precision I want, I'd like to be able to have eight digits following the decimal point, and a single digit to the left of it.

Comment: Well what level of precision and range *do* you want? It looks like you could easily use `decimal` from your example, but if you want more digits than that, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: I've updated the text to be more specific. Thanks...

Comment: Right, well `decimal` is fine for that. `double` would be fine too, given than it's got 15-16 digits of precision, but `decimal` would be more simply predictable, and I'd argue that it's more representative if you care a lot about the exact digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

From the link:

> Precision 28-29 significant digits
>
> Approximate Range (pasting doesn't give the formatting of the exponent etc. so just check out the link.)

Comment: Cool. Do you know why https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 again uses the term "approximate range" still? Is this type subject to the possible approximation that applies to float?

Comment: @BenjiFB I'm not sure. But _maybe_ that's because we're dealing with base 10 digits, so different numbers will be a little different depending on how they align with base 2. (Just a guess, though.)

Comment: @BenjiFB They likely give an approximate range because very few people are interested in the *exact* limits. This is like stating that normalized IEEE-754 single precision (`float`) values can express magnitude in the approximate range [3.2e-38, 3.4e+38], rather than stating the precise limits [1.17549435e-38, 3.40282347e+38]

Answer (score 1):

> what options or guarantees does one have in terms of precision

base on the doc an Wikipedia float has a precision of 7 significant decimal digits precision

something like 1234567 or 1.234567 or 0.0000001234567

> Why is an approximation necessary in this context

because it is not exact. IEEE 754 floating-point value is (2 − 2−23) × 2127 ≈ 3.402823 × 10^38

though you might be able to get a number like 3.4028239999 × 10^38 and the last 5 digits (99999) cannot be trusted

Comment: Got it. But ultimately, the first 7 digits can be "trusted" with a float? It's only the digits following which cannot be trusted?

Comment: @BenjiFB yes. Though you want to be careful when doing massive calculation with float. you will be losing some precision each time and eventually you might end up with 0 precision

Comment: @BenjiFB Actually [only 6 digits can be trusted in the worst case](http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/). (For example, 9.86e-4 to 7 digits is 9.860001e-4 .)

Comment: @RickRegan what I mean is if you do for (int i = 0; i < int.Max; i ++) floatVar = floatVar * floatVar; then you might end up with 0